# Getting C-string from local copy of returned std::string

Tags: c++, return-value-optimization

I am trying to debug a problem related to the scope of the character array contained within a std::string. I have posted the relevant code sample below,

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

const char* objtype;

namespace A
{

std::string get_objtype()
{
  std::string result;
  std::string envstr( ::getenv("CONFIG_STR") );
  std::size_t pos1 = 0, pos2 = 0, pos3 = 0;
  pos1 = envstr.find_first_of("objtype");
  if (pos1 != std::string::npos)
    pos2 = envstr.find_first_of("=", pos1+7);
  if (pos2 != std::string::npos)
  {
    pos3 = envstr.find_first_of(";", pos2+1);
    if (pos3 != std::string::npos)
      result = envstr.substr(pos2+1, pos3 - pos2 - 1);
  }
  const char* result_cstr = result.c_str();
  std::cerr << "get_objtype()" << reinterpret_cast<long>((void*)result_cstr) << std::endl;
  return result;
}

void set_objtype()
{
  objtype = get_objtype().c_str();
  std::cerr << "Objtype " << objtype << std::endl;
  std::cerr << "main()" << reinterpret_cast<long>((void*)objtype) << std::endl;
}

}

int main()
{
  using namespace A;
  std::cerr << "main()" << reinterpret_cast<long>((void*)objtype) << std::endl;
  set_objtype();

  if (::strcmp(objtype, "AAAA") == 0)
    std::cerr << "Do work for objtype == AAAA " << std::endl;
  else
    std::cerr << "Do work for objtype != AAAA" << std::endl;
}
```

This was compiled and executed on MacOS 12.3 with g++ 4.2.1. The output from running this is as follows,

```
$ g++ -g -DNDEBUG -o A.exe A.cpp
$ CONFIG_STR="objtype=AAAA;objid=21" ./A.exe
main()0
get_objtype()140210713147944
Objtype AAAA
main()140210713147944
Do work for objtype == AAAA
$
```

My questions are these: 
The pointer value printed from main() and get_objtype() are the same. Is this due to RVO?
The last line of output shows that the global pointer to C-string is ok even when the enclosing std::string is out of scope. So, when does the returned value go out of scope and the string array deleted? Any help from the community is appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: The returned string in get_objtype() is destroyed right after the statement. i.e. after hitting the semicolon. It's just that the address that objtype is pointing is not overwritten with any other data. Hence you are still seeing the value "AAAA".

Comment: BTW, what are you trying to acheive with this example ? Unless you are doing something different, make the code simpler and easy.

Comment: I am trying to understand an existing piece of code.

Comment: Compiled and executed on Mac OS 12.3? When did that come out?

Comment: @Michael. Are you not getting this output?

Comment: In the question the OP says _This was compiled and executed on MacOS 12.3 with g++ 4.2.1._ I was wondering (jokingly) when MacOS 12.3 came out.

Answer (score 1):

The pointer value won't change, but the memory it points to may no longer be part of a string.

`objtype` is invalid on the line right after you set it in `set_objtype()` because the result of get_objtype() isn't saved anywhere, so the compiler is free to kill it there and then.

It may work, but it's accessing invalid memory, so it is invalid code and if you rely on things like this, you will eventually run into big problems.

Comment: Thanks. So will the compiler create a temp string before calling c_str() on that?

Comment: There is an anonymous string "existing" until the semicolon on the line `objtype = get_objtype().c_str();` The get method returns an actual string (on the stack).

Answer (score 0):

You should look at the disassembly using objdump to check if its RVO.

But, from experiments I did (making result global and making copies of it), it looks like c_str is reference counted.